# FLAT FILE SITE: PHP5 Master Template Without Database

Tags: php, performance, apache, templates

Dear folks,
Imagine a flat php site without database with hundreds of files having the same variables defined in all of them eg `$read` `$look` and `$buys`.

**page1.php**

```
<?
$blue= ".....";
$bell= ".....";
$beam= ".....";
?>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?
$blue= ".....";
$bell= ".....";
$beam= ".....";
?>
```

**etcettera.php**

Now, as soon as I invent a new variable, say `$bike` or `$beaf` then I have to go through all those template files in order to add to them `$beaf = ""` or else there undefined there. I miss a master template so to say... Any ideas/hints/code/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Is there any smarter way of template management without use of database, making it easer to maintain these templates?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a database?

Comment: Because Im afraid of it being too difficult and meanwhile getting up and going with programming database, would forget about caring the contents... Does this answer make anyu sense? Perhaps im seeing it wrongly... I *thought* there are good reasons why sometimes one should avoid using database, but it seems I'm wrong?

Comment: Rather or not you use a database really depends on what kind of information you are "storing", and how you are using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A templating engine like [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) might help you.  Twig supports [template inheritance](http://www.twig-project.org/doc/templates.html#template-inheritance), which allows you to define a master template that all child templates inherit from:

**master.html.twig:**

```
<html>
  <head><title>{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %}</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>{% block pageHeading}{% endblock %}</h1>
    {% block body}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**child.html.twig:**

```
{% extends master.html.twig %}
{% block title}Child Page{% endblock %}
{% block pageHeading}Weclome!{% endblock %}
{% block body}
<p>My name is {{ name }}.  Today's date is {{ today|date('n/j/Y') }}.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**PHP code:**

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
  'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
));
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('child.html.twig');
echo $templater->render(array("name"=>"Mike", "today"=>new DateTime()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create a file that has an [__autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) function in it, `include` it at the top of your `page1.php` (and so on), then create some class like this:

```
class MyVars {
  const book = "Book";
  const apple = "Apple";
}
```

and you can use them like `MyVars::book` and `MyVars::apple` in your PHP files.

Answer (score 1):

Your system with flat variables floating around is one of the thing to avoid.

Use a framework that helps you not doing such bad errors or just use Smarty

[Zend](http://www.google.com/search?q=zend%20framework&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=ivnslb&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=4uaITfGPCoXsOdymgI8O&ved=0CAYQpwUoAA)